# The antipodal map $\mathbb{C}P^1\to\mathbb{C}P^1$ in coordinates

Tags: calculus, general-topology, differential-geometry, spherical-coordinates

I know that on $S^2$, we have the antipodal map $a:S^2\to S^2, (x,y,z)\mapsto(-x,-y,-z)$. But I know that we can identify $S^2$ with $\mathbb{CP}^1$, using the diffeomorphism $$
\Psi:\mathbb{CP}^1\to S^2, 
\Psi([w_0:w_1])=\frac{1}{|w_0|^2+|w_1|^2}\left(2\text{Re}(w_1\overline{w_0}), 2\text{Im}(w_1\overline{w_0}),|w_0|^2-|w_1|^2\right)
$$
But now, I want to see how the antipodal map looks like in coordinates on $\mathbb{CP}^1$. I know it should be something like $[z_0:z_1]\mapsto[\overline{z_1}:\overline{z_0}]$, but I have been trying to compute it all day now and did not really progress. Could anyone help please?

Comment: It cannot be the map $[x,y]\mapsto [\overline x,\overline y]$ because this has fixed points (it corresponds to a reflection of $S^2$). The homeomorphism $\Psi$ you have written down is implemented by stereographic projection. From this point of view the antipodal map interchanges the origin and the point at infinity of the Riemann plane $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$. In terms of homogeneous coordinates this corresponds to an interchange of charts (I do not mean coordinate change!). You'll notice an extra twist too. (Hint: try making use of the inverse to $\Psi$)

Comment: I think that my problem boils down to the inverse of $\Psi$, I can't seem to find a global expression for this, only things that work locally and that becomes difficult

Comment: The map $S^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\cup\infty$ is $(x,y,z)\mapsto\frac{x}{1-z}+i\frac{y}{1-z}$ (this is $\infty$ when $z=1$). The map $\mathbb{C}\cup\infty\rightarrow\mathbb{C}P^1$ is $z\mapsto [z,1]$, $\infty\mapsto [1,0]$. The composite $S^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}P^1$ is $(x,y,z)\mapsto [x+iy,1-z]$ (with the obvious adjustment at $z=1$). You should check this, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{CP}^1$ is defined as the quotient space
$$(\mathbb C^2 \setminus \{0\})/\sim$$
where $(w_0,w_1) \sim (w'_0,w'_1)$ if there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $\lambda (w_0,w_1)  = (\lambda w_0,\lambda w_1) = (w'_0,w'_1)$. We have
$$\Psi([w_0 :w_1]) = \frac{1}{|w_0|^2+|w_1|^2}\left(2w_1\overline{w_0},|w_0|^2-|w_1|^2\right) \in \mathbb C \times \mathbb R = \mathbb R^3 .$$
You want to see what $\Psi^{-1}(-\Psi([w_0:w_1]))$ looks like. Define
$$A : \mathbb C^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb C^2 \setminus \{0\}, A(w_0,w_1) = (-\overline{w_1},\overline{w_0}) .$$
Clearly $A$ is a diffeomorphism.
We have
$$A(\lambda w_0,\lambda w_1) = (-\overline\lambda \overline{w_1},\overline\lambda \overline{w_0}) = \overline\lambda (-\overline{w_1},\overline{w_0}) = \overline\lambda A(w_0,w_1)$$
which means that $(w_0,w_1) \sim (w'_0,w'_1)$ implies $A(w_0,w_1) \sim A(w'_0,w'_1)$. Therefore $A$ induces a diffeomorphism $\bar A : \mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ given by $\bar A ([w_0:w_1]) = [-\overline{w_1}: \overline{w_0}]$. We get
$$\Psi(\bar A ([w_0:w_1])) = \Psi([-\overline{w_1}: \overline{w_0}]) = \frac{1}{|-\overline{w_1}|^2+|\overline{w_0}|^2}\left(2\overline{w_0}(-w_1),|-\overline{w_1}|^2-|\overline{w_0}|^2\right) \\ = \frac{1}{|w_0|^2+|w_1|^2}\left(-2w_1\overline{w_0},|w_1|^2-|w_0|^2\right) = - \Psi([w_0:w_1]) .$$

This shows that $\Psi^{-1}(-\Psi([w_0:w_1])) = [-\overline{w_1}: \overline{w_0}]$.